# How to combine tables with different numbers of columns in R?

Tags: r, model, data-manipulation, data-management

I know it must be a simple fix but I've been stuck on this for ages. I've got three tables, two with three columns, one with two columns. I want to combine them to show, for each statistical test, how many times a particular model was the best one. Below are the tables I have at the moment. What's the best way to combine them so I have R_Squared, AIC and BIC as the column headers and Quadratic, Polynomial and Linear as the row names with the results (and a zero for Linear under the R Squared column)? Thank you so much for your help!

[image: Here are the tables I have at the moment]

Comment: please do NOT post images of your data.. use `dput()`.... possible solution: `data.table::rbindlist()` with the `use.names` and `fill`-arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Not the most elegant solution but does create the desired table.

```
library(dplyr)

# Data
R_Squared <- data.frame(Polynomial = c(283), Quadratic = c(2))
AIC <- data.frame(Polynomial = c(201), Quadratic = c(60), Linear = c(24))
BIC <- data.frame(Polynomial = c(196), Quadratic = c(62), Linear = c(27))

df <- bind_rows(AIC, BIC, R_Squared)
# add row names
row.names(df) <- c('AIC','BIK','R_Squared')
# returns the transpose of df
df <- t(df)
```

Output:

```
           AIC BIK R_Squared
Polynomial 201 196       283
Quadratic   60  62         2
Linear      24  27        NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of doing this with `table` objects:

```
# Data 
R_Squared <- structure(
  data.frame(matrix(c(283,2), ncol = 2)),
  class = "table",
  dim = c(2),
  dimnames = list(
    c("Polynomial", "Quadratic")
  )
)
AIC <- structure(
  data.frame(matrix(c(201,60,24), ncol = 3)),
  class = "table",
  dim = c(3),
  dimnames = list(
    c("Polynomial", "Quadratic","Linear")
  )
)
BIC <- structure(
  data.frame(matrix(c(196,62,27), ncol = 3)),
  class = "table",
  dim = c(3),
  dimnames = list(
    c("Polynomial", "Quadratic","Linear")
  )
)
```

These are dummy objects after an output of `table()`. Now we make a `list` of these tables with `mget` and identify unique columns.

```
## combine 
mylist <- mget(c("R_Squared", "AIC", "BIC"))
cols <- unique(unlist(sapply(mylist, names)))
```

afterwards, we combine everything considering differences in the colnames with `setdiff()`:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(mylist, function(x) {
  x[setdiff(cols, names(x))] <- NA
  x
}))

#          Polynomial Quadratic Linear
#R_Squared 283        2         NA    
#AIC       201        60        24    
#BIC       196        62        27
```

Hope this helps.